# Can a database be considered idle even when continuously replicating?

Tags: couchdb

I'm currently considering CouchDB for a project (still in the research phase). What I want is many users, each with its own database (for authentication purposes), as well as one big read-only database to which they're all replicated, so I can generate reports and make a dashboard. For now let's assume all the databases are running on the same machine and in the same process.

Normally, only a small fraction of the human users will be online and doing things, so I should be able to keep the max_dbs_open setting a lot lower than the total number of users. CouchDB should have no problem determining which ones are idle.

However, I'm worried the extra database will throw a wrench into this. Will having continuous replication from all user databases into the one big database keep them all awake all the time? (And if so, is that bad? Will actually logged-in users lose any priority advantage and get thrashed at bad times?)

Or is CouchDB smart enough to consider a database idle as long as it's not being queried or written to, even if there's an ongoing continuous replication session? Note the replication would only be in one direction: the big database only watches for changes from the user databases.

Suggestions for other ways to approach this problem are also welcome. I'm vaguely aware that if I'm going to have enough to users for this to be a problem, that one database is going to be an unwieldy beast.

Thanks!